# Using class as event identifiers

Tags: c#, class, enums, identifier, state-machine

I'm working on a state machine implementation for game objects in a video game. I'd like this state machine to be simple to use; in order to invoke a change of state a 'Raise' method should be called on the state machine. My current design involves using a generic type as the event identifier:

```
stateMachine.Raise<Event>();
```

with the definition:

```
public void Raise<EventType>() where EventType : Event
```

The state machine then finds states that handle this event type and updates the state according to the transitions they provide. I considered originally using a string to recognize event types, e.g.:

```
stateMachine.Raise("Event");
```

or and Enum:

```
stateMachine.Raise(GameObject.Event);
```

But I feel that both these methods pose issues. Strings are two flexible and can't be error checked at compile time to ensure that they're valid. Enums can't be extended, limit the event's available to each class that extends GameObject, make the event calls longer unnecessarily and cause issues with type checking inside the state machine. However the method of using a class as an identify means that I declare the events inside the GameObject like this:

```
protected class SomeEvent : Event {}
protected class OtherEvent : Event {}
...
protected class AnotherEvent : Event {}
```

Despite being elegant, I feel this is somehow going to become a code smell or terrible practice at some point, I get the impression I'm abusing the purpose of classes. Eventually I will have hundreds of empty classes littering my code base which I can see being a potential issue. What really is the best alternative for this?

Comment: You say an enum would be a limitation as it cant be extended. But why would you want to extend the signaling of the event? It is merely a trigger for the state machine to change. Would you want these events to be more than a signal in the future?

Comment: The Event Aggregator pattern typically employs something like this. Usually you would have some information attached to the event, but sometimes not. It is useful when you want to be notified of something but there may not be a fixed publisher with which you can subscribe.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I don't think that each event would be extend very much but it does mean that each new event class must extend Event because the Raise method checks for that. It could also allow for specific types of state machines, e.g.: HierarchicalStateMachine which expects HierarchicalEvent for its Raise method which may be used differently.

Comment: @mikez I'm uncertain about information at this time. Currently events are used in this system simply to change between discrete states, e.g; Door is Opened, Event 'Close' is raised, Door is now Closed. Perhaps I'm thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: @sydan: If you specialize your events too much you risk encountering exponential explosion of your transitions. Information attached to events limits this and the number of events (see the Mood example in my answer, a bit contrived but conveys the idea)

Comment: @sydan Presumably you will have multiple Door objects and you will need to identify which specific Door's state to change. I think the problem you have is having too many events in the first place and none of the proposed schemes solve that problem. The system will be difficult to understand when there are too many kinds of events.

Comment: This question would be a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This question belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Hi @CharlieKilian, why is that? I'd like to know because I don't want to make mistakes in the future.

Comment: See [What topics can I ask about?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) These links should give you a better idea of what is on topic at SO.

Comment: @CharlieKilian, I think that my question meets these criteria very suitably. Which of the given criteria do you think it does not meet?

Comment: This is the part that I felt was off topic: "I get the impression I'm abusing the purpose of classes. ... What really is the best alternative for this?"  There is not just one good answer to this question. Any answer will be opinion-based and invite extended debates on the merits of the answers. That is more the purview of programmers.stackexchange.com. (Though I will note that my vote to close only attracted two other votes, so perhaps the rest of the community disagrees with me! And that is okay too!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're writing for a video game - and unless this is a feature of the game - your events and states should be defined in your specs, so the list of possible events should not be moving a lot once defined; so go for classes that derive from a common ancestor.

Why not enums or strings? Because enums and strings don't carry data. You usually want to have some data going with your events, because it will let you group your events by families. You don't need a `GrumpinessIncreaseEvent` and a `JoyIncreaseEvent`, rather a `MoodChangeEvent` with some information in it (what type of moods are affected, by how much, etc)

What's more you can have some events that are loosely typed for potential known unknowns you may have later (an event with an object property that is then cast to some type at runtime, for example)

---

re: OP's comment: I indeed think that you should use instances instead of type. You wouldn't pass `PunchInFace` but `new DamageEvent() {type = Damage.PUNCH, source= PuncherGuy.Fist, Target=PunchedGuy.Face}` because this kind of event is friendlier to plenty of components in your game (physics engine, score engine, etc...)

Once again it depends on how the game is done (which makes me think that the question should in fact be closed because it is opinon-based)  but when you raise a `PunchInFaceEvent` by type, what can you say? Who punched who? Where? When? etc...

Comment: Do you suggest that I should change my implementation to use actual objects as opposed to class types? e.g.:
`Raise(Event event)`
As opposed to my current method? 
My implementation may be too complex, there is another higher level of interaction between GameObjects using messages, e.g. one object might send the message 'PunchInFace' to another.
If that other object receives that type of message it will handle it and pass some event into the state machine, say: 'Hurt'. The state machine itself decides whether or not this causes a transition from Happy to Grumpy and perhaps Healthy to Injured.

Comment: Answer to your edit: I see the merit to this, I think I need to go away an consolidate my idea of what events and messages are going to be and which parts of the system are going handle which bits of information they expose.